# Shell command using strings to determine the file name

Tags: vb.net, string, shell

I just wondered if somebody could provide a quick yes/no answer or even a touch more information/assistance on using a shell command within VB.NET.

As it stands, depending on the selected item of a number of combo boxes, I want my shell command to launch the correct file (which is a .bat in this instance.

My code for the shell currently stands as follows:

```
 Shell("C:\Users\Damon\Desktop\batchtest\" & strServer & "_" & strGameType & "_" & strMap & ".bat", AppWinStyle.NormalFocus)
```

This, however, brings up an error advising that the file cannot be found. The file does indeed exist, however, I wonder if the shell command is only trying to execute:

```
enter  Shell("C:\Users\Damon\Desktop\batchtest\", AppWinStyle.NormalFocus)
```

possibly because it is not recognising the strings to include within the file path?

Thanks in advance.

Damon

Comment: make sure all those strings have the value you think they do, and that they have any required backslashes.  use console.writeline to see what  it all resolves to: `console.writeline("C:\Users\Damon\Desktop\batchtest\" & strServer & "_" & strGameType & "_" & strMap & ".bat")`

Comment: Hey again Plutonix. Thanks for the answer. I was slightly confused with the purpose of console.writeline and how to test this without debugging the app. I opted for a messagebox to display the contents of ("C:\Users\Damon\Desktop\batchtest\" & strServer & "_" & strGameType & "_" & strMap & ".bat") and this displayed correctly.

Comment: a) console.writeline does not interrupt program flow, MsgBox is modal. b) EITHER the string is wrong OR the file does not exist (different kind of wrong)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
I just wondered if somebody could provide a quick yes/no answer
```

Short answer: **Don't use `Shell` !**

---

Extended answer:

You can use `Process` Class memthods to run a process, this class contains numerous properties to personalize your process.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx

an example would be this:

```
Dim file As String = _
"C:\Users\Damon\Desktop\batchtest\" & strServer & "_" & strGameType & "_" & strMap & ".bat"

Dim p As New Process With {.StartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo With { _
        .FileName = "CMD.exe", _
        .Arguments = String.Format("/C Start ""Title"" ""{0}""", file), _
        .UseShellExecute = False, _
        .CreateNoWindow = False, _
        .RedirectStandardOutput = True
    }}

p.Start()
p.WaitForExit()
```

---

First do a simple check to see if the file-path really exists, if yes then run it:

```
Dim file as string = _
"C:\Users\Damon\Desktop\batchtest\" & strServer & "_" & strGameType & "_" & strMap & ".bat"

If Not IO.File.Exists(file) Then
    msgbox("Does not exist: " & file)
Else
    Process.Start(file)
End If
```

Comment: Hey bud. Thanks for the suggestion. I think I will use the check to see if the file is there to ensure the application does not fall over if this does not exist, that is bad practice on my part. I will have a look at the MSDN link provided. Much appreciate the direction.

Comment: I'm glad to be of help, please mark one of the answers as accepted if question is resolved.

Comment: Hi again, I am receiving the following message: The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform. Any ideas on the cause of this? It seems bloody obvious but strange as I am running Windows 7 and one would assume this would be fine.

Comment: Please try to run the process by following the instructions on the example that I've supplyed you to configure and launch a process, that will work 100%, but if you will can you try to do it like this: `Process.Start("CMD.exe ""/C Start """" """ & file & """""")`

Comment: Hi mate, tried the second option but I am currently having some random issues with a showfrm command. Once I have fixed it I will get back to you.!

Comment: Hi again mate, yes, that does work! Taking a look through the different options for process method. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

Your string literal is wrong. It's trying to use the back-slashes as escape characters, especially the `\b`. You need one of the following two changes:

```
Shell("C:\\Users\\Damon\\Desktop\\batchtest\\" & strServer & "_" & strGameType & "_" & strMap & ".bat", AppWinStyle.NormalFocus)
```

or

```
Shell(@"C:\Users\Damon\Desktop\batchtest\" & strServer & "_" & strGameType & "_" & strMap & ".bat", AppWinStyle.NormalFocus)
```